# Why am I getting an "object is not subscriptable" despite trying to script a 2D array?

Tags: python, debugging

`I'm kind of experienced with Python and I am super confused as to why I am getting an object error even though I am fairly certain that I instantiated the 2D arrays properly. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I also would like to ask if anyone knows how to replace character specifically within a 2D array with another.

```
row, col = (10, 10)

playerOneBoard = [[0]*row]*col
playerTwoBoard = [[0]*row]*col
playerOneFound = [["_"]*row]*col
playerTwoFound = [["_"]*row]*col

def placeDestroyer(Player):
    if Player  == 1:
        for a in playerOneBoard:
            print(a)

        print("\nWhat is the x cooridnate of the destroyer?")
        x = int(input(" "))
        print("\nWhat is the y coordnate of the destroyer? (Please use integer values)")
        y = int(input(" "))
        
        x-= 1
        y-= 1
        
        playerOneBoard.insert[x, "D"]
        
        for a in playerOneBoard:
            print(a)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ZMf.png)

The goal for the program was to insert a letter "D" in a specified spot in the 2D array`

Comment: What is `playerOneBoard.insert[x, "D"]`? Did you mean: `playerOneBoard[y][x] = 'D'`?

Comment: `insert` is a function, you have to _call_ the function. You can't directly add brackets to a function itself like that. Did you mean something like `playerOneBoard.insert([x, "D"])`?

Comment: `insert` would effectively make your board *bigger*.. You want to *change* the value at a particular position, not add a new position altogether.

Answer (score 1):

For the error, you just have a typo: the error message tells you to look at line 21. On line 21, it should be `insert(x, "D")` instead of `insert[x, "D"]`

> I also would like to ask if anyone knows how to replace character specifically within a 2D array with another.

if I want to replace the current character at `board[row][column]` I would do it like this: `board[row][column] = 'D'`

Also, I noticed that you have a very common and insidious bug:
`playerOneBoard = [[0]*row]*col` is NOT what you want.

Try the following example:

```
playerOneBoard = [[0]*3]*3
print(playerOneBoard)
playerOneBoard[1][1] = 1
print(playerOneBoard)
```

You'll see that you've changed the 2D matrix in more than one place. This is because making a 2D matrix like this doesn't make 3 different rows, it just makes a matrix composed of 3 of the SAME row.

You'll want to do `[[0]*row] for _ in range(col)]` instead.

See: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)